# In JMeter 5.3, variables do not work in functions

Tags: groovy, jmeter

[image: Code screenshot]

I use groovy to write a script. In the screenshot, No. 1 works, No. 2 doesn't work, No. 3 works. It's normal to print No. 1 separately. No. 2 and No. 3 are written in a custom function. The parameter passed in by No. 2 is still ${re} instead of value

Answer (score 1):

Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts, your "No 1" and "No 3" work because they're [GStrings](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_gstring_and_string_hashcodes) and your "No 2" conflicts with JMeter Functions and/or Variables syntax.

So I would recommend moving your function into "Parameters" tab like:

[image]

Also according to [JSR223 Sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

> Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
> When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code **as caching would only cache first replacement.** Instead use script parameters.

So if your `${secretKey}` variable changes from iteration to iteration only first value will be used and this may ruin your test so you might want to change it to `vars.get('secretKey')` expression

Also be aware that according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.4.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-4-1-released-td5739226.html) (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity.

Comment: I use__ After the groovy() function, I successfully solved my problem. As you said, I wrote the custom function in the parameter, like this:${__ Sms_ String_ Encrypt(${__ groovy(import groovy.json.JsonSlurper ; new JsonSlurper().parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString()).result,)},${secretKey},2,url)} .Thank you